# Need to write a slightly advanced query with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So say this is a table:

```
------------------------------------
|post_id|meta_tag|meta_value       |
------------------------------------
|1      |address |123 Example Lane |
------------------------------------
|1      |name    |John Doe         |
------------------------------------
|1      |email   |johndoe@gmail.com|
------------------------------------
|3      |foo     |bar              |
------------------------------------
```

Basically what I want to do is select * from a `post_id` only if one of its`meta_tag` values has address in it. Then I want to be able to echo out all of the `meta_value`s for each `post_id`.

Hope that's not too confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Check out `EXISTS` e.g. `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM \`a table\` WHERE post_id=$post_id AND meta_tag='address')`

Comment: @AmazingDreams why are you using `HAVING` when a `WHERE` statement is useable in this situation?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused between `HAVING` and `WHERE EXISTS`

Comment: If you are using such a database struture, you would probably be better off using a nosql database as EAV tables are notably poor performers in relational databases.  This is a tructure that will not scale well. It is hard to query and takes away all the things of value in a relational database that let you specify required fileds and use the correct datatypes and other data integrity issues. In general this is a poor design choice when you use a realtional database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the rows where the post has at least one address tag:

```
select *
from t t1
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.post_id = t1.post_id and t2.meta_tag = 'address'
             );
```

If you want *exactly* one, there are various approaches.  Following the same logic:

```
select *
from t t1
where 1 = (select count(*)
           from t t2
           where t2.post_id = t.post_id and t2.meta_tag = 'address'
          );
```

If you really want only the *post_id*s that have one address tag:

```
select post_id
from t t1
group by post_id
having sum(t1.meta_tag = 'address') = 1;
```

(Or make that `> 0` if you are looking for any `address` tag.)

Comment: ok this looks like it makes sense, however what exactly do I do with t, t1, t2? I'm not really sure what this is specifying besides the 1 table name that I have.

Comment: @pwneth . . . `t` is your table name (whatever that is).  `t1` and `t2` are tables aliases.  Using table aliases is always a good idea.  In some cases, such as the first two queries, they are needed to express the logic correctly.

Comment: great, this worked perfectly when I change t.post_id to t1.post_id :)

Comment: ok now this seems to be pulling up all the meta_values when post_id contains address as a meta_tag. However, is there a way to seperate the results based on post_id?

Comment: @pwneth . . . Perhaps you want to add `order by post_id` to the query?